# Design of Database Tables for persisting Excel Sheet Into

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I would like to persist many excel sheets all with the same columns but different data into a database. What is a better practice?

1) To have one table containing all the data (called excelsheet) with an additional field to identify which fields belong to which excel sheet?

Or
2) To have the two tables: excelshset and columns, where excelsheet table has one entry for each excelsheet and it has a 1:M relationship with the fields in the field table.

I feel like I would go with example 2, but what are the actual advantages in terms of design in choosing option 2 over 1?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you are storing data in a database, you'll want to store it in a normalized form.  Excel spreadsheets are generally not normalized so you would generally want multiple tables (though what you describe in option 2 does not appear to make sense).  If you want to avoid doing any sort of transformation, store the XLS file as a binary object in the database (a `BLOB` in Oracle, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is to that the best approach is to design a normalized database that meets your business requirements.  Then add a staging table to accept your excel data.  Finally, write whatever it takes to process the excel data and write it to your real tables.

Comment: THank you for the reply. I am new to db, what is a stating table in this case, can I assume it is a table with the exact columns of the excel sheet? And from there then I can proceed to process the data in the staging table into other normalized tables?

Comment: A staging table exists to accept and then manipulate data before it goes into your database.  It will have a field for every field you are accepting, plus some extra ones maybe.  It depends on the details of the processing.  The contents of the staging table should not be considered permanent.  They are likely to be replaced whenever you import data.